# What exactly does "/scoreboard @a <obj1> = @a <obj2>" do?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm developing a multiplayer minigame, but haven't been able to get any of my friends to help me on testing yet. I need to set EVERY players **`internalCash`** score to their **`cash`** score, but cannot use **`/execute`**, since it needs to run for non-op players.

It would be INCREDIBLY elegant if I could simply use

```
/scoreboard players operation @a internalCash = @a cash
```

but it doesn't seem to work properly with `@e`, which scares me. Could someone please tell me if I need to develop a clever workaround for this, or if this will do.

*edit* Oops! Kinda need the "players operation " part. :P

Comment: Hmmmmm... I seem to recall there being a way to do this, but `/scoreboard @a objective = @a objective2` isn't it. I'll look into this.

Comment: @Unionhawk its the players operation under scoreboard

Comment: @ModDL Yeah, `/scoreboard players operation @a targetObjective = @a sourceObjective`, I *think*, but I'm not confident enough/haven't tested the operation of this enough to post such things as an answer right now. If you want to. go for it

Comment: Same here, haven't tested this out. Never had to use operation before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/execute` does not require the targets to be OP'd and is very necessary to use in order to do what you're trying to do. `/scoreboard` operations requires one of the two selectors to resolve to a single target, so you cannot use `@a` with `@a`.

Using `/execute`:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players operation @a[c=1] internalCash = @a[c=1] cash
```

Comment: It doesn't? Hmm. I thought I had trouble with that before. What you suggest is what i originally had (except the @a[c=1] were @p selectors instead). So I DON'T have to go through and redo EVERYTHING. Thank goodness. Also, thanks for the help! :) New here, so my upvote doesn't count for your answer score :(

Comment: @sharpturn From the [wiki](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#execute): "executes the specified command as if executed by the specified target(s) with operator-level permission". Using `@a[c=1]` is preferred if /execute's target is also `@a`, because it is the only selector capable of targeting dead players. If you used `@p` instead of `@a[c=1]`, dead players will still run the /scoreboard command but will instead target the next-nearest living player, which changes the wrong target's scores. You could also use `@e[type=Player]` instead of `@a` for /execute and use `@p` for /scoreboard.

Comment: You might be confusing execute with JSON-based commands in books, signs and tellraw, which do run with the user's permission level (hence `/trigger` exists).

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I was probably just confusing /tellraw clickEvents with /execute commands. I only recently got back into commands in minecraft, so still very slightly rusty. Still capable of making shelves in one command block, though! Proud of that one.

Comment: @MrLemon Just a tiny correction: signs, unlike /tellraw or books, actually behave like /execute in that the clicker is given elevated permission to run the command. Oddly though, the coordinate origin of execution is the sign's coordinates, but the player is still the designated executor as sender bias applies to them.